# Is there a way to add Angular App created in VS Code to Visual Studio Solution which contains the API? Also any way to deploy them both together?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular app I created in VS Code. I have created an API in Visual Studio using ASP.NET Core for this angular app.

Now I want to deploy this app on Azure or any other similar service. Preferably free because this is just a sample application. I just want to learn the process.

I have a couple of doubts.

1. Do I have to publish and host both the apps differently? Or can I do it together if I can get them in the same Visual Studio solution?
2. How can I move the Angular app into the Visual Studio solution?
3. Is there any free service I can use to learn the process? I looked in to Azure and it offers a free account for a year.

Comment: [Use the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to publish and host both the apps differently?

First we really need to discuss what these words mean, so here are my definitions:

Host - An environment for *code or executables* to run in.

Publish - the act of compiling (if necessary) and moving/copying *code or executables* to a host for them to *run in*.

Obviously there is a lot of gray area here.  Docker containers need to be hosted, but you also publish/deploy code and executables to/inside them.

Publishing (deploying) is a verb and a host is a noun, so your question doesn't quite make sense.

You can, in a single "task", publish/deploy both applications to 1 or more hosts.  You can also have separate publish/deployments per type of application to 1 or more hosts.

> Or can I do it together if I can get them in the same Visual Studio solution

This is possible with .net-core with the .net-core hosting environment setup to host SPA resources.

> How can I move the Angular app into the Visual Studio solution?

You can use following instructions for [Use the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) or download one of many [Visual Studio Angular Project Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adentum.QuickApp-ASPNETCoreAngularXProjectTemplate) and copy your app into it.

> Is there any free service I can use to learn the process?

Both Azure and Amazon Web Services provide some limited (time constraint) website you can use to host your applications.

Update 1

> How can I deploy both of these together to a host?

Deploying is a whole skill in and of itself.  It totally depends on how you want to deploy.  You can deploy in Visual Studio, but that's honestly not a very *enterprise* solution (and I've never seen anyone ask for that skill set in an interview).  There are Continuous Integration products built into suites of software and there are a lot to choose from:

- [Azure DevOps Release PipeLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops)
- [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
- [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines)
- [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)
- [CodeFresh](https://codefresh.io/)

And this is by far not an exhaustive list.  It would be best to ask a new question specific to the one you want to learn.

> Won't it cost twice as much if I deploy them separately?

Depends on both the Deployment Suite you want to use and the host.  Hosts typically don't care about deployments, just bandwidth.  That being said, the bandwidth to deploy them together or separately is minuscule so there won't be much difference in terms of bandwidth.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm new to this and thus the confusing words. How can I deploy both of these together to a host? And if I have to do it separately, how do I do it? Won't it cost twice as much if I deploy them separately?

Comment: Thank you. I have a better understanding now.